# Определить содержит ли массив целые числа от 1 до K

Tags: java, алгоритм

Написать функцию, которая берет параметрами непустой массив `A`, состоящий из `N` целых чисел (отсортированных в неубывающем порядке) и целое число `K`, проверяет содержит ли A числа `1,2, ..., K` (каждое число от `1` до `K`) по крайней мере однин раз, и не сожержит других чисел. Например, используя следующие значения:

```
int[] A = {1,1,2,3,3};
int K = 3;
```

функция должна возвратить `true`. А если задать

```
int[] A = {1, 1, 3};
int K = 2;
```

или

```
int[] A = {1, 1, 2, 3};
int K = 2;
```

функция должна возвратить `false`.

Я пробовал написать следующую функцию, но она работает неправильно

```
public boolean function(int[] A, int K){
  int n = A.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    if (A[i+1] >= A[i]+1)
      return true;
    if (A[0] != 1 && A[i] != K)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

В чем может быть ошибка? Большое спасибо всем если кто найдет ошибку в коде.

ЗЫ: забыл добавить что сложность должна быть не хуже `O(n)`.

Comment: почему если следующее число больше предыдущего больше чем на один то возвращается true? Плюс судя по всему из цикла выполняется только первая итерация, так как в любом случае будет заход в ветку с каким-нибудь return

Comment: @Grundy Потому что оно больше предыдущего на порядок. Возможно надо использовать рекурсию, но сложность должна быть не больше O(n).

Comment: если больше на порядок, то как оно может входить в последовательность `1,2, ..., K`?

Comment: @Grundy Здесь как раз разница равна 1.

Comment: `A[i+1] >= A[i]+1` -> `A[i+1] = 5` и `A[i]=1` - условию удовлетворяют, но совсем не значит что входят в последовательность до 3

Comment: A[i+1] >= A[i]+1 , а как это работает ? Проверяет первые 2 элемента и сразу возвращает true?

Comment: @RomanC По моему у вас неточный заголовок. Судя по описанию вы хотите проверить не то, что массив содержит челые числа от 1 до K, а то, что он состоит из всех чисел от 1 до K и только из них. Так же посмотрите мой вариант ответа.

Comment: Простите, а проверяемый массив является отсортированным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку массив отсортирован, достаточно сделать следующее:

1) Проверить, что первый элемент равен 1
2) Проверить, что последний элемент равен K
3) Пройти в цикле от второго до последнего элемента, проверяя, что разница с предыдущим не превышает 1

Таким образом, ваше решение было практически верным, ошибка вкралась только в условии внутри цикла и возврате true вместо false в случае нарушения порядка.

```
public boolean function(int[] A, int K){
  int n = A.length;
  if (A[0] != 1)
      return false;
  if (A[n-1] != K)
      return false;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    if (A[i] - A[i-1] > 1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли мне доделать это.

Comment: Вернёт `true` на (`[1, 1, 2, 3]`, `3`), что неверно

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Судя про примеру в вопросе, это как раз верно.

Comment: @MBo, ой, простите меня, слепого) Я уже подзабыл точную формулировку вопроса хД

Comment: Но все равно. Вбейте тогда массив `{ 1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 }` и ту же тройку. Я клонил к тому, что в Вашем алгоритме кроется ошибка, позволяющая числам быть меньше предыдущих, а это уж точно неправильно

Comment: @Kir_Antipov В условии есть указание `отсортированных в неубывающем порядке` - в этом случае такой входной массив недопустим. Для задачи же с несортированным массивом нужен другой подход.

Comment: @MBo и то верно. Все, простите за беспокойство, пойду-ка я просплюсь хД

Answer (score 2):

Пришло вот такое решение в *лоб*:

```
private static boolean check(int[] array, int k) {
    if (k == 0 && array.length > 0)
        return false;

    if (array[array.length - 1] != k || array[0] != 1)
        return false;

    for (int number = 1; number <= k; number++)
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(array, number) < 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Асимптотичекая сложность `O(n*log(n))` Уверен, что можно быстрее

**UPDATE**

Решение работающее за `O(N)`

```
private static boolean check(int[] array, int k) {
    if (k == 0 && array.length > 0)
        return false;

    if (array[array.length - 1] != k || array[0] != 1)
        return false;

    int index = 0;
    int number = 1;
    while (number <= k) {
        while (index < array.length && array[index] == number)
            index++;

        if (array.length == index)
            return true;

        if (array[index] == number + 1)
            number++;
        else
            return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Сложность должна быть надо не больше O(n)

Comment: я ошибся с оценкой, последний алгоритм работает за линейное время и от  k не зависит

Answer (score 1):

Напишите ф-ю, которая будет генерировать массив от 1 до K (оно же макс).

```
void count(int *array, int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

,
и дальше в теле будет проверять, входит ли i элемент массива в заданный массив A., если хотя бы раз не входит - false, если все ок - true.

Comment: зачем генерировать, если можно просто проверить `<K`?

Comment: и так что получается O(n*k), надо не больше O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Фактически ваша задача является задачей о сравнении множеств:

```
public boolean function(int[] a, int k) {
    if (a.length < k) {
        return false;
    }
    Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return set.size() == k && IntStream.range(1, k + 1).allMatch(set::contains);
}
```

Comment: Можете оценить сложность?

Comment: В данном случае создаются два экземпляра `HashSet`, основанных на `HashMap`. Сложность операций `put()`, `get()` и `contains()` для `HashMap` - O(1) в лучшем случае и O(n) в худшем, зависит от реализации `hashCode()`. Полагаю, что поскольку речь идёт о натуральных числах, то `hashCode()` будет иметь хорошее распределение и соответственно сложность операций `put()` и `get()` будет O(1). Таким образом я полагаю, что сложность данного решения будет O(a.length + 2 * k). Думаете, я не ошибаюсь? Тут наверное можно сделать оптимизацию. Если a.length < k можно сразу же возвращать `false`.

Comment: Изменил код. Теперь сложность в лучшем случае O(1), в худшем O(a.length + k)